# Is it possible to purchase a UPS whose alarm can be disabled? Or must I physically disconnect the speaker by disassembling and modifying the unit?

Tags: power-supply, ups

I am working in a setting where we can expect to lose power several times a day and I want to get a UPS (uninterruptible power supply) in order to keep the computers running.

Are there any uninterruptible power supplies which do not emit loud high-pitched screeching sounds every-time that I lose power?

How much time would it take to disassemble the UPS, cut the wires to the speaker, cap the speaker wires with wire nuts, and put the housing back-together?

Comment: Get a good quality UPS.   You need a fair size one to run several computers. Allow 400 to 500 watts for each computer/monitor.  Then look at the GUI Setup screen to see if the sound can be turned off. Mine just beeps quietly.

Comment: This question is absolutely out of scope.  I just want to point out there is typically a button to silence the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know about any model/brand with no audible alert (or with a software option to disable the alert).

Time to modify an UPS will depend on the model - my guess is *half an hour* at maximum.

Don't expect to see a speaker with cables, but a piezo buzzer in a tiny plastic housing (probably black, round shape, about 10mm diameter and 6mm height, with a center hole) mounted directly to a circuit board - an UPS won't have to play music, but just to emit those noise. So you might have to open two solder connections to remove the buzzer. Just leave the contacts disconnected.

Comment: “Unfortunately I don't know about any model/brand with no audible alert (or with a software option to disable the alert).” Pretty much any UPS configuration software — if the UPS supports connecting to a computer — allows one to disable the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

### You want to find a UPS that you can connect to — and configure — via a software configuration tool.

> “Are there any uninterruptible power supplies which do not emit loud high-pitched screeching sounds every-time that I lose power?”

This really all depends on what make, model and brand you are looking for. But the general rule of thumb is if you can configure the UPS via vendor provided software, you can control the alarm sound. If you can’t do that? You will have to open up the UPS and disconnect the alarm speaker cables to achieve silence.

> “How much time would it take to disassemble the UPS, cut the wires to the speaker, cap the speaker wires with wire nuts, and put the housing back-together?”

Depends on the unit and how it’s assembled, but I would not recommend going down that route since many UPS’s already allow you to disable the alarm via configuration software.

For example, some of the APC UPS’s can be connected to a computer via a USB cable and using their PowerChute software — such as the [APC Back-UPS CS Series](https://www.apc.com/us/en/faqs/FA158940/) — you can disable the audible alarm. Ditto with the Smart-UPS models that begin with SU, SUA, SURT, or SUM; you can do [what is outlined here](https://www.apc.com/us/en/faqs/FA284138/) to disable the alarm.

There is also some cool command line software called the [APC UPS Daemon](http://www.apcupsd.org) that can allow you to control an APC UPS from the command line easily without having to install the official PowerChute GUI software. It’s available for Mac and Windows as precompiled binaries as well as RPMs and Deb packages for Linux in addition to pure source code that you can compile an pretty much any system.

[This blog post from 2012](https://masxio.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/how_to_disable_beep_alarm_from_apc_ups/) does a decent job of explaining specifically how to use the APC UPS Daemon software to disable alarms. Here is the command line flow once you get the APC UPS Daemon software software installed and `apctest` is available:

```
sudo apctest
 
2012-11-18 23:30:50 apctest 3.14.8 (16 January 2010) debian
 Checking configuration ...
 Attached to driver: usb
 sharenet.type = DISABLE
 cable.type = USB_CABLE
 
You are using a USB cable type, so I'm entering USB test mode
 mode.type = USB_UPS
 Setting up the port ...
 Hello, this is the apcupsd Cable Test program.
 This part of apctest is for testing USB UPSes.
 
Getting UPS capabilities...SUCCESS
 
Please select the function you want to perform.
 
1) Test kill UPS power
 2) Perform self-test
 3) Read last self-test result
 4) View/Change battery date
 5) View manufacturing date
 6) View/Change alarm behavior
 7) View/Change sensitivity
 8) View/Change low transfer voltage
 9) View/Change high transfer voltage
 10) Perform battery calibration
 11) Test alarm
 12) View/Change self-test interval
 Q) Quit
 
Select function number: 6
 
Current alarm setting: ENABLED
 Press...
 E to Enable alarms
 D to Disable alarms
 Q to Quit with no changes
 Your choice: Select function: d
 
New alarm setting: DISABLED
 
1) Test kill UPS power
 2) Perform self-test
 3) Read last self-test result
 4) View/Change battery date
 5) View manufacturing date
 6) View/Change alarm behavior
 7) View/Change sensitivity
 8) View/Change low transfer voltage
 9) View/Change high transfer voltage
 10) Perform battery calibration
 11) Test alarm
 12) View/Change self-test interval
 Q) Quit
 
Select function number: 6
 
Current alarm setting: DISABLED
 Press...
 E to Enable alarms
 D to Disable alarms
 Q to Quit with no changes
 Your choice: Select function: q
 
1) Test kill UPS power
 2) Perform self-test
 3) Read last self-test result
 4) View/Change battery date
 5) View manufacturing date
 6) View/Change alarm behavior
 7) View/Change sensitivity
 8) View/Change low transfer voltage
 9) View/Change high transfer voltage
 10) Perform battery calibration
 11) Test alarm
 12) View/Change self-test interval
 Q) Quit
 
Select function number: q
 
2012-11-18 23:32:59 End apctest.
```

Comment: Why are you answering off topic questions?

Comment: @DavidPostill Because I don’t believe this question is completely off-topic. I believe there is a shipping aspect here, but the general concept of how to disable UPS alarms is solid.

Comment: You voted to close it. So you should not have answered it.

Comment: If you are going to answer it please edit the question to make it on topic first.

Comment: @DavidPostill Edited the title of the question and some text to make it less shipping and more “Does this exist?” which I believe is on topic. As for why I flagged it as off-topic, honestly it was an initial instinct until I reread it and then decided to answer. Regret not removing the flag sooner. Voting to reopen.